# How to update a null value in a column - Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-update

```
--Create sample table for illustration of issue 

CREATE TABLE SAMPLETABLE ( 
[Order_ID] int,
[Individual_ID] int,
[SAMPLECOLUMN] varchar(50), 
[FACILITY] int,
[ORDERCODE] int
) 
GO 

--Populate column with values including null for sample column

INSERT INTO 
SELECT 
TABLEX.TABLE_ID AS [Individual_ID],
TABLEX.ORDER_ID AS [Order_ID],
NULL AS [SAMPLECOLUMN],
TABLEX.FACILITY_ID AS [FACILITY],
TABLEX.ORDERCODE AS [ORDERCODE]
FROM TABLEX 

--UPDATE NULL values of SAMPLECOLUMN with string values 
UPDATE SAMPLETABLE
SET
SAMPLETABLE.SAMPLECOLUMN = CASE WHEN SAMPLETABLE.ORDERCODE IN ('1') THEN 'THISWILLBETHESTRING'
END
FROM SAMPLETABLE
WHERE SAMPLETABLE.SAMPLECOLUMN IS NULL
```

What I am trying to do is to replace the null values that I initially populated my table with using the update statement. I receive the error: 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'THISWILLBETHESTRING' because null has a data type of int, whereas the values that I want to use to update it are string. Keep in mind that in the update statement the SAMPLETABLE.ORDERCODE comes from the same table that I am updating.

Here is the DDL to illustrate the issue:

```
-- DDL and sample data, start
DECLARE @start TABLE
(ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
data VARCHAR(20) NULL,
ordercode int);

INSERT INTO @start ([data], [ordercode])
VALUES
(NULL, '1')
,(NULL, '1')
,(NULL, '2');

-- DDL and sample data, end

SELECT *
FROM @start;

DECLARE @end TABLE
(ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
data VARCHAR(20) NULL,
ordercode int);

INSERT INTO @end ([data], [ordercode])
VALUES
('STRINGVALUEIWANT', '1')
,('STRINGVALUEIWANT', '1')
,('ANOTHERSTRING', '2');

-- DDL and sample data population, end
SELECT *
FROM @end;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*incorporate*"? How will this `UPDATE` be any different from other SQL statements?

Comment: By incorporate I mean how do I action this in Microsoft Visual Studio? I think my syntax seems correct, but I am unable to actually get the update to work.

Comment: I have updated the original post to better clarify what my ask is.

Comment: Your `SAMPLETABLE` does not have `TYPE_OF_ORDER` field.

Comment: I have edited the original post to more carefully reflect the problem. TYPE_OF_ORDER is indeed the SAMPLECOLUMN that I created in the table.